# ¿Es posible llamar un método creado en una clase JPnanel a otra clase JPanel?

Tags: java, netbeans

quería saber si es posible llamar a un método creado en una clase JPanel a otra clase JPanel?
Lo que quiero hacer es colocar este método que esta en una clase JPanel dentro de otro método en una clase JPanel. Lo intente hacer por medio de instanciación pero no lo logre, no puedo acceder al método que quiero. Si alguien sabe como hacerlo me podría ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: Hola, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.


Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 


Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. 

Cuando resp

Comment: Hola, no elimines la pregunta y vuelvas a agregarla nuevamente, como te habíamos comentado, realiza tus preguntas con base en [ask], agrega lo que trataste o investigaste.